# how to convert json text to png in python

Tags: python, json, python-imaging-library

I have files uploaded to a server via ajax calls.
The files contain images.
I need to read the uploaded files and convert them to .png in python.
How can I achieve that?

The images, stored as .txt files, look like this:
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAm4 ... RK5CYII="

Thanks!
FP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string starting from iV... is your actual bytes data of png converted in base 64. decode the string and with as binary to file, you will get your image

```
import base64
png_str = "iVBORw0 ... NS=="
png_bytes = base64.b64decode(png_str) # get your raw bytes

with open('test.png', 'bw') as fid: # write as binary file
    fid.write(png_bytes)
```

if it helps , please vote up.